# onKeyup event myfunction is not returning expected matching data as entered in the text box from the <td>list <td>obj it should filter data from list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

home.jsp

```html
<input type="text" id="myContractNumberInput" ng-model="contractno"
ng-change="getContractnNo()" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="contractno"
placeholder="Contract Number.." size="35">
<hr>
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="contractTypeData in contractDetailsList">
    <table id="myContractTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>{{contractTypeData.contractId}}</td>
        <td>{{contractTypeData.contractDes}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myContractNumberInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myContractTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above function on key event must return the entered  matching data from the list object as it is not returning the expected data which is entered in text box

Comment: Try giving (keyup)="myFunction($event.target.value)" and receive the value in the function myFunction(value) {
}

Comment: hi Praveen i m getting the value in myFunction but the output i am not getting as expected from the function which is  matching data %like% from the list object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular filter for filtration of result using search input field, please find below example, also there is no need to use **myFunction** for this filtration, and for any other custom logic, you can create your own custom filter (follow this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.contractDetailsList = [
  {'contractId': 1,
  'contractDes': 'one'},
  {'contractId': 2,
  'contractDes': 'two'},
  {'contractId': 3,
  'contractDes': 'three'}
  ]

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <input type="text" id="myContractNumberInput" ng-model="contractno" name="contractno" placeholder="Contract Number.." size="35">
    <hr>
        <table id="myContractTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Description</td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="contractTypeData in contractDetailsList | filter:contractno">
            <td>{{contractTypeData.contractId}}</td>
            <td>{{contractTypeData.contractDes}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, appreciate if you can vote the answer, thanks